# How can I send proxy w/ aioquic HTTP/3

Tags: python, quic, http3

I am trying to understand how HTTP/3 works. Ultimately, my goal is to send HTTP/3 request to a host with proxy and receive a response back.

The host I am trying to reach only accepts HTTP/3 Connection.

There is a library that takes care of heavy lifting to initiate a HTTP 3 connection however they don't demonstrate how proxy can be passed into the packets.

```
https://github.com/aiortc/aioquic/blob/main/examples/http3_client.py
```

I am running the following file after cloning the repo like this:

```
python3 examples/http3_client.py 'https://www.truepeoplesearch.com/'
```

Doing so does route the request via HTTP/3 using QUIC protocol. How can I send the same request behind a proxy with IP, pOrt, username and password of the proxy.